# Encadenar modificaciones en script awk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

Soy nuevo en awk. Estoy intentando realizar un conjunto de modificaciones en un archivo `.csv` con awk. El archivo tiene la siguiente forma:

```
"DAY_OF_MONTH", "DAY_OF_WEEK", "OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER","OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE","ORIGIN"
1,3,"EV",20366,"ORD"
2,2,"AH",15164,"BAR"
```

Las modificaciones a realizar son:

1. **DAY_OF_WEEK:** En el archivo se listan los dias de la semana como 1, 2, 3, etc. Quiero reemplazar el número en concreto por el dia de la semana que corresponda. Por ejemplo, si el valor es 1 corresponderá a Domingo, si el valor es 2 corresponderá a Lunes y así sucesivamente.
2. **ORIGIN:** En el archivo se lista el nombre entre "". Por ejemplo, "ORD". Quiero quitar las comillas. **La cabecera no se puede modificar**

Hasta el momento he realizado lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{FS = ","}
{
#Modificamos DAY_OF_WEEK
if ($2 == 1)sub($2,"Domingo"); 
if ($2 == 2)sub($2,"Lunes");
if ($2 == 3)sub($2,"Martes");
if ($2 == 4)sub($2,"Miércoles");
if ($2 == 5)sub($2,"Jueves");
if ($2 == 6)sub($2,"Viernes");
if ($2 == 7)sub($2,"Sábado");
#Modificamos ORIGIN
if (NR!=1) $5=substr($5,2,3);
print
}
```

El problema es que las primeras instrucciones if funcionan correctamente y lo veo en la salida. Sin embargo, al ejecutar la siguiente instrucción esta no se lleva a cabo. A continuación, muestro un ejemplo de la salida que obtengo:

```
"DAY_OF_MONTH", "DAY_OF_WEEK", "OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER","OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE","ORIGIN"
 1,Martes,"EV",20366,"ORD"
 2,Lunes,"AH",15164,"BAR"
```

La salida debería ser:

```
 "DAY_OF_MONTH", "DAY_OF_WEEK", "OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER","OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE","ORIGIN"
  1,Martes,"EV",20366,ORD
  2,Lunes,"AH",15164,BAR
```

Pero obtengo que los campos no aparecen separados por "," mientras que la cabecera si:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: no pongas print, simplemente di `$1 = sub($2, "Domingo")`, sigues con el resto de cambios y finalmente pones un `print`, que mostrará el contenido modificado.

Comment: No entiendo la instrucción. Porqué columna $1?. La substitución depende del valor contenido en cada celda. Si es 2 serà X si es 1 sera Y.

Comment: Ah pues `$2 = ...`. La esencia está en que modifiques todas las variables que quieres y luego, solo luego, hagas `print`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' no consigo que la modificación de quitar las comillas funcione. El comando funciona bien si lo ejecuto solo pero cuando lo pongo en el script falla algo. Alguna idea?

Comment: debes usar NR en mayúsculas

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' lo he cambiado y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: a mí con `if (NR!=1) $5=substr($5,2,3);` me ha funcionado (en tu código  dice $10, pero en el ejemplo está en $5)

Comment: Me faltaba añadir $5... Sin embargo, cuando veo el resultado por pantalla. Los campos no aparecen delimitados por "," como el principio. Ahora estan separados por un espacio. Edito el post.

Comment: como indicó Thor en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/453183/83), debes definir OFS. OFS es el "output field separator", es decir, el separador que delimita los campos cuando se imprimen. En general no hay que definirlo, pero si toqueteas los campos estás volviendo a crear el registro y, por tanto, debes volver a dárselo. Por tanto, `FS = OFS = ","` te debería solucionar ya el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Sugeriría usar un formación de nombres de los días y reemplazar desde allí, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN { 
  FS = OFS = ","
  split("Domingo,Lunes,Martes,Miércoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sábado", num2day)
}
NR > 1 {
  $2 = num2day[$2]
  gsub(/"/, "", $5)
}
1
```

Corre asi:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Produce:

```
"DAY_OF_MONTH","DAY_OF_WEEK","OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER","OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE","ORIGIN"
1,Martes,"EV",20366,ORD
2,Lunes,"AH",15164,BAR
```

Comment: el gsub no funciona.